# How to obtain split and dividend adjusted prices using alpaca_trade_api?

Tags: python, alpaca

I am modelling the minute prices of stocks and I obtain the data using the `alpaca_trade_api` from Python:

```py
api = tradeapi.REST(api_key, secret_key, 'https://paper-api.alpaca.markets')
data = api.get_barset('AAPL', 'minute', end=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 5, 10, 00, 0, 0, 
                              timezone('US/Eastern')).isoformat(), limit=1)
```

However, the data is not adjusted on splits or dividends, and it will screw up the models if the splits or dividends occur (i.e. stock prices will have a very sharp increase or decrease). Is there a good way to obtain the adjusted price automatically?

Comment: still TBD: https://forum.alpaca.markets/t/adjusted-ohlc-prices-are-missing-from-iex/431